# Build iOS app from Cordova Command Line

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When building and uploading a iOS app our approach is like this.

1. Create the mobile app and put the Cordova configuration
2. run `cordova platform add ios` then basically load the generated folder / project into XCode
3. Configure and select the *Signing* on XCode
4. Use XCode to build the iOS app and upload the Archive to TestFlight

In what way all these can be done with the Cordova command-line?